# How to login to Gmail with Node.js / Request

Tags: node.js, request

I'm trying to login to Gmail to scrap a few data.

I can access the Google login page easily with Node.js and Request with the following Coffrescript code. There are a bunch of hidden input fields I'd like to get, such as "service" or "dsh"

```
# REQUIRE
request = require("request")
querystring = require("querystring")

# Parameters
url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail"

# Main Stuff
request url, (error, response, body) ->
  if not error and response.statusCode is 200
    console.log "Home page loaded for " + url
```

But how do I post the Email and Passwrd form data after this?

NB: using Zombie.js is not an option, since I can't make it work on my machine

Comment: I'd use a Node.js IMAP client if I were you. Assuming, you're trying to view emails.

Comment: Just to clarify.. I need to scrap some data that are on the web pages, but not accessible by IMAP

Answer (score 2):

Gmail is well known for its extensive use of javascript to load data.

Therefore you can just make a normal http request and expect to load actual data.

If you really want to login and retrieve your emails. 
You going to need to simulate a browser, with headless browser like [zombiejs](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)/[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)